# Can I change the auto-update behavior, when connected to my personal hotspot?

Tags: macos, tethering, cellular-data

Yesterday, I ran suddenly out of cellular data volume (I can only use 6GB per month) for this month while my MacBook was connected to the personal hotspot on my iPhone. If found out, that macOS downloaded an update automatically, because it treated the personal hotspot like any other hotspot.

Is there any option to tell macOS, not to treat my personal hotspot like a "real" WiFi-network? Since the symbols for both types of connections are different, I guess there must be an option somewhere.

Comment: Are you tethering over wifi or Bluetooth? Does this happen over both?

Comment: @NoahL WiFi. Bluetooth is enabled as well to set up the connection without even touching my phone, but the data is transferred via WiFi. Not sure how I could test this with Bluetooth-only.

Comment: Instead of connecting via wifi, click on the Bluetooth option in the menu bar. Click on the name of your phone, then click "Connect to Network". That's how you connect to a hotspot via Bluetooth

Comment: @NoahL yes. But how can I test, if the OS will be updated automatically as well with this setup?